# Задать размер string

Tags: c++

Нужно в `string` всегда хранить 300 символов.

Как я понимаю память выделяется динамически при присвоении к примеру:

```
string ex = "Example";
```

Мне нужно явно присваивать каждому символу значение,

```
 ex.at(100) = '2';
```

но при выполнении кода будет ошибка, т.к. не была выделена память, возможно ли указать размер строки явно, как в массиве символов ?

Такой вариант не очень

```
for(int i=0;i<300;i++)
   ex += " ";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` в этом отношении имеет почти ту же внешнюю интерфейсную спецификацию, что и `std::vector`.

Скажите ей

```
ex.resize(300);
```

и будет вам строка размера `300`. Эта версия дополняет строку (если необходимо) до размера `300` нулевыми символами. А вариант

```
ex.resize(300, 'a');
```

соответственно, дополнит символами `'a'`.

Вот чего нет, так это конструктора, соответствующего первой версии `resize`, т.е. при конструкции символ-заполнитель придется всегда указывать явно

```
std::string ex(300, 'a');
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
string s(300, ' ');
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/8Hqa7f

Comment: Кстати я тестировал, некоторый код на сервисе ideone и это просто отвратительно...просто тупо не ловит ошибки хотя они есть! Так что ideone лучше не использовать

Comment: @MaximPro: Разумеется. Сервисы, не предоставляющие доступа к настройкам компилятора, всерьез рассматривать не приходится.

Comment: @AnT: "всерьёз" имеет смысл рассматривать код только на вашем железе, с доступным вам ПО. Для всех остальных, ideone демонстрирует, что код ожидаемый вывод производит (хотя бы для какой-то комбинации железо+ПО). Что однозначно лучше отсутствия этой информации.

Comment: @MaximPro: можете пример привести?

Comment: ideone в режиме С молча пропускает `int *p = 42;` Пробуем `char *c = 0; int *p = c;` - снова тишина. Чтобы такого добиться, надо специально целенаправленно "давить" диагностические сообщения, ибо в умочательных настройках GCC будет хотя бы "предупреждение" в ответ на такие ошибки.

Comment: @jfs: Нет, ни в коем случае. В вопросах по языку *мое* железо и доступное *мне* ПО вообще никакой роли не играют даже отдаленно. Трудно даже предположить, откуда могла возникнуть такая посылка. Это надо какой-то манией величия страдать, чтобы на основе "своего ПО" делать такие далеко идущие проекции.

Comment: @AnT: "[ваш] код .. на вашем железе" употреблены в том же смысле как в известном изречении: "the only benchmark that matters is the code you're running." Очевидно, что поведение вашего ПО в production "играет роль".

Comment: @jfs: Ну, знаете ли, кто-то скажет, что вообще ничто под луной не играет роли, кроме диких пчел. Не надо насильно тащить в вопросы по языку программирования темы production, пока никаких конкретных предпосылок для этого не появилось. Сломается production - вот тогда и рассмотрим production.